# MongoDB em produção

Tags: mongodb

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza MongoDB, já estou chegando ao fim do seu desenvolvimento e só comecei a pensar agora em como seria feita a instalação desse banco em ambiente de produção. Durante o desenvolvimento as *collections* foram sendo criadas conforme eram sendo necessárias, mas nunca realmente parei para pensar em como eu iria restaurar isso em produção.

Como isso é geralmente feito? Devo criar apenas as *collections* vazias de início e deixar a aplicação rodando? Ou eu deveria utilizar o `mongodump`? Se o `mongodump` é a maneira recomendada, como eu faço para que ele não faça o backup dos *documents* e contenha apenas as *collections* com seus *indexes*?

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso depende do que está armazenado em cada collection. Eu costumo identificar as que representam dados criados pelos usuários versus os dados que são necessários para a aplicação rodar (tipo listas de países e estados). Esses últimos eu chamo de dados obrigatórios e crio scripts para criar e preencher essas collections (ou mesmo tabelas quando uso DB relacional.)

Você pode também usar `mongodump` para copiar esses dados obrigatórios mas eu acho importante ter o script e uma origem desses dados que não seja seu banco de desenvolvimento. Imagine se você depender desse banco para poder criar o banco de produção e der um azar de corromper o banco antes de conseguir copiar.

Os dados dos usuários normalmente não há sentido em serem copiados para produção.

O mongodump também será útil quando você estiver configurando os backups do seu banco de produção (que espero que seja algo que você planeje fazer também).

Comment: Entendi, vou fazer isso mesmo que você disse, montar um script para a criação das *collections* e de seus respectivos índices. Obrigado pela resposta sergiopereira.